# how to retrieving id on the basis of any column in table in database ?

Tags: c#

i want to retrieve id of customer from customer table on the basis of list item value in drop_down list in my Database(DAO)file in C# . how can i do that can any one help me .

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You need to post code so we can see what your DAO looks like. Essentially your DAO will generate some sql like: select id from Customer where dropdownlistItem = @selecteddropdownlistItem;

Comment: @user5297806 please send your code and explain.